# Unable to execute command ng build in iis hosted asp.net web app using cmd.exe

Tags: c#, iis, angular-cli

I want to execute ng build using c# code to build my angular project. I have hosted by c# application on  IIS. When I am executing code I am getting error:

ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n

I have created another application that I have not hosted on IIS and I am executing that with locally using visual studio. In that same code is working property. I am unable to figure out issue with iis. My code is as below.

```
private void buildAngular()
        {
            try
            {

                Process p = new Process();
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\AngularToBuild\AngularProject";
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                //p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c echo off > fff1.txt";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c ng build";
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                p.Start();

                p.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);

                var err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                var msg = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine("error", msg, err);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }

        }
        private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exit time:    {0}\r\n" +
                "Exit code:    {1}\r\nElapsed time: {2}");
        }
```

Comment: which is the application pool identity?

Comment: application pool identity: DefaultAppPool

Comment: that is the application pool, not the application pool identity. The application pool identity is the account  it runs under.

Comment: oh sorry. In ApplicationPoolIdentity "ApplicationPoolIdentity" is selected under DefaultAppPool .

Comment: Changing DefaultAppPool to LocalSystem worked. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng.cmd` is located in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm` but the default application pool identity has no permissions to access that folder.

Grant NTFS read permissions to application pool identity and make sure that folder is included in the `PATH` environment system variable.

The default app pool identity for DefaultAppPool is `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.. You need to grant permissions to this account.

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Go to `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming`
3. Right click on `npm`
4. Select `Properties`.
5. Select `Security` tab
6. Click on `edit` button
7. Click on `add`button
8. Enter `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` on the text box
9. Click `Ok` button
10. Ensure `Read and Execute`, `List Folder and Content` and `Read` Permissions are checked.
11. Click `Ok`
12. Click `Ok`

Comment: Grant NTFS read permissions to application pool identity. How to do that??

Comment: Changing DefaultAppPool  to  LocalSystem worked. Now it is working.

Comment: Updated answer to give you instructions to add NTFS permissions. LocalSystem is too much powerfull account. It can do anything on your system. If I suggested you to change the account to SYSTEM account, I would receive a lot of down votes

Comment: Hi Thank you for details explanation. I tried that and gave required permission as suggested by you. But I am getting new error this time.

fs.js:1690
      binding.lstat(baseLong);
              ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\username'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1690:15)
    at toRealPath (module.js:170:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:219:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:541:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)