# Publish Angular app on iis - error only on iis side

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, publish, angular10

I created application .net 3.0 + Angular 8 in visual studio. Then I uptaded angular to ver. 10. When I run app locally everything is ok but when I publish it on iis I got this error:

> no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Websites\App\ClientApp\package.json'

I've change Startup.cs

> services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
> {
> configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/App";
> });

but this not help.

ver 8 worked on iis without any issues.

my packsage.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run App:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Edit
With @Yiyi You help  I've move on. Now I got this error

```
The error output was: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

I updated everytning (angular, node, etc), added variable npm to PATH, copied package.json and node_module to project, added permission to app_pool

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Your .NET server might be running in **Development** mode, so it's trying to run an Angular server instead of looking at the built Angular project; hence why it's looking for a package.json so that it can run the `npm start` script.

Set your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to **Production** (or any other value than **Development** depending on your needs), with the following command in the cmd (or using the GUI):

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Production"
```

And then run your published app again, it shouldn't try to look for package.json anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to check 'C:\Websites\App\ClientApp\package.json' exists or not.Run app locally or run on IIS,the path may be different because it's not a full path.So If 'C:\Websites\App\ClientApp\package.json' not exists,you need to add your packsage.json to the path `C:\Websites\App\ClientApp`.

Comment: Locally everythink works. I will try thank you! But I do not understand why I have this error on the iis side. Previously (I think) there was no package.json in this location either(on iis).

Comment: The relative path depends on the current location of your project.So when locally you may have packsage.json in your local project somewhere.And when publish,the path depends on the publish project location,so it may not have a packsage.json in your publish project somewhere.

Comment: ok so do I need package.json on iis side? Is it a problem with publish?

Comment: I think you need it.When publish,if you use a static file locally,and it's not a full path,you often need to put the file to your publish folder somewhere.

Comment: Maybe. But why it worked correctly before the Angular update?

Comment: I think maybe angular needs it.You can refer to [this](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages).`The packages listed in the dependencies section of package.json are essential to running applications.`

Comment: ok now I had The error output was: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
but I installed Angular/cli :/ Still dont get it why there is so many problems after updating angular

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549316/unable-to-execute-command-ng-build-in-iis-hosted-asp-net-web-app-using-cmd-exe)